# How to add items from combo box into array

Tags: vb.net

I want to add the following combobox items into the array called "Numbers". Below is what I have so far. How do I add each combobox item into the array? Thanks.

```
    number.Items.Add("One")
    number.Items.Add("Two")
    number.Items.Add("Three")
    number.Items.Add("Four")
    number.Items.Add("Five")
    number.Items.Add("Six")
    number.Items.Add("Seven")

    Dim Numbers(6) As String
    Dim count As Integer
    For count= 0 To 6
        Numbers(count) = number.Text
    Next count
```

Comment: use `List(Of String)`... for example : `Dim num As New List(Of String): For x... num.Add(number.Items(x).Text)...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're very nearly there..

```
Dim Numbers(6) As String
    Dim count As Integer
    For count = 0 To 6
        Numbers(count) = Number.Items(count).ToString
    Next count
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this code (it convert all items to array of string, so You can skip defining array size) :

```
number.Items.Add("One")
number.Items.Add("Two")
number.Items.Add("Three")
number.Items.Add("Four")
number.Items.Add("Five")
number.Items.Add("Six")
number.Items.Add("Seven")

'convert all items to string array
Dim Numbers = number.Items.Cast(Of String).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `CopyTo()` built-in method

```
Dim Numbers(ComboBox1.Items.Count - 1) As String
ComboBox1.Items.CopyTo(Numbers, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual way round would be to put the items into an array and then either use that as the datasource for the combobox or simply add them with `.AddRange`:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim numbers As String()

    Private Sub SetUpNumberComboBox()
        numbers = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven"}
        number.Items.AddRange(numbers)
        ' alternatively:
        'number.DataSource = numbers

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        SetpUpNumbersComboBox()

    End Sub

End Class
```

[For anyone who uses the designer to add items, that way, you don't need to go through the (relatively) fiddly designer to change the items, you just edit the code.]